# Прозрачность statusbar - Android, Java

Tags: java, android, layout

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сделать так чтобы картинка как бы сливалась с баром? Возможно ли это? Я видел один ответ, но он не подходит вообще. Мне надо чтобы просто статус бар был просто прозрачным и всё. Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У коренного лайаута актвити укажите атрибут `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Если вы используете родной appBar, то проблем быть не должно. Если свой, могут быть проблемы, например, аппбар будет рисоваться выше положенного, залезая под статус бар. Это все лечится и гуглится